# How to unit test java code, which is using Reflections to populate subTypesOf a class?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, reflection, spring-mvc-test

This is my code:

```
protected void loadConverters() {
        // load all available converters
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.mypackage.MyClass");

        Set<Class<? extends ContentConverter>> processors = reflections.getSubTypesOf(ContentConverter.class);
        for(Class<? extends ContentConverter> processorClass : processors) {
            try {
                if(Modifier.isAbstract(processorClass.getModifiers())) {
                    continue;
                }

                ContentConverter processor = processorClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
                ReportOutputType type = processor.getOutputType();
                if(type == null) {
                    LOGGER.warn("Class {} does not return a valid ReportOutputType, is not being loaded for processing.", processorClass);
                    continue;
                }

                // register
                AVAILABLE_CONVERTERS.put(type, processor);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Cannot instantiate step processor class", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

So I'm writing the output to a variable AVAILABLE_CONTAINERS. I want to know if there is a way I can mimic the sub classes & conduct unit testing of the above code.

Comment: Is this in fact a static method?

Comment: No this is not static.

Comment: Then why is it doing nothing except manipulating a constant map?

Comment: The idea here is to populate diff. types of converters, ex - csv, json, as-is, delimiter etc. 
All of such converters will have their own specific ConverterClasses. Hence, we're using reflection to populate the converters, based on their availability.
So the map, as such, is not constant. Today I only have a csv converter. But going forward, we will also have json, delim, etc.